# Any way to apply staticmethod to all class methods?

Tags: python, static-methods

Is there any way to apply staticmethod to all methods of a given class.

I was thinking we can access methods in its metaclass (in **new** of metaclass) and apply staticmethod, but i am not aware of syntax.  Can any one please shed light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [a module (as suggested by mgilson)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14898860/722121) is a better option, if you *really* have a good use for this (I can't think of one), it's relatively easy with [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and a class decorator:

```
import inspect

def staticmethods(cls):
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
        setattr(cls, name, staticmethod(method.__func__))
    return cls

@staticmethods
class Test:
    def test():
        print("Test")

Test.test()
```

All the class decorator does is loop through the methods on the object with `inspect.getmembers()`, then overwrites the function with a `staticmethod()` of the original (unbound) function.

Note that I would use a module over a class for this, and probably also just manually call `@staticmethod` on each function over doing it this way (as this, for example, breaks my editor's inspections). This answer is given to show it's possible, because it's a pretty simple implementation.

Answer (score 4):

If none of the methods share any state, there's not much of a reason to have a class at all.  a module with functions is probably a better idea ...

Comment: +1, I was just about to say this. A class with only static methods is equivalent to a module, and much less easy to implement.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Yeah.  You can't subclass it, but that doesn't really make any difference either ...

Comment: Yes, a module with those functions a better idea, but i was grouping logically related functions into a class

Comment: @Neil You can group logically related functions into a module - it still signifies a relation.

Answer (score 1):

[mgilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14898860/1235039) is best, but to add another pattern which is often used for defining a class as a namespace, you could also instantiate the class, overwriting the class name:

```
class Test:
    def a_static_method(self, arg1, srg2):
        pass

Test = Test()
```

Be aware, though, that after this `Test` is actually a class instance, which might be misleading depending on how you're using it.